# Strapi 3 and Nuxt 2 Localhost:1337/admin not Loading

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi, nuxt-strapi

My Nuxt is version 2.15.8
My Node is v14.15.3
I have installed nuxtjs/strapi as a module.

I have also installed strapi v3 wrapper for nuxt 2 as described [here](https://strapi-v0.nuxtjs.org/).

My module is called in nuxt.config.js
`'@nuxtjs/strapi',`

My strapi options is also set to localhost:1337, but opening the localhost:1337/admin gives me nothing.

```js
strapi: {
    // Options
    url: process.env.STRAPI_URL || 'http://localhost:1337',
  },
```

Am I missing something? or is this just not doable with Nuxt v2 ?

Comment: Is your back office (Strapi server) running?

Comment: @kissu I might have missed a big step which is to install a strapi setup in my nuxt project folder using the [quick start guide](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start.html), is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, you need to have the actual Strapi back office for it to work properly.

Following this guide fixed OP's issue: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start.html